# Catalan's conjecture in $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Catalan's conjecture (Mihăilescu's theorem) states that the only case of two consecutive integer powers is given by the equation $3^2-2^3=1$. We can easily verify that it is not valid in some prime fields $\mathbb F_p$. For example, one has 
$$\begin{cases}3^3-4^2=1\pmod5\\5^3-3^5=4^4-5^5=1\pmod7\\8^3-6^7=10^7-3^3=1\pmod{11}\end{cases}$$

The problem I want to try is the following:

Prove or disprove that for all $\mathbb F_p$ with $p\gt 3$ there is an example of $x^a-y^b=1\pmod p$, with $xy\ne0$ other than the trivial one $3^2-2^3=1$

Comment: Take $y=0$ and apply little Fermat for $x^{p-1}=1$.

Comment: $x^{p-1} - y^{p-1} = 1 \bmod p$ doesn't have many solutions with $xy \ne 0$. If $(a,b)$ are fixed then there are $p + O(\sqrt{p})$ solutions by the Weil bounds, where the constants depend on $a$ and $b$. In particular, for large $p$, there are always solutions.

Comment: @user655377: see at Dietrich Burde's first comment,  please.

Comment: I see that the problem is easier than I imagined. In particular, the Pigeonhole Principle can be used.

Comment: You probably want to exclude trivial cases like the following. If $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$, then the mapping $x\mapsto x^a$ is bijective. Meaning that any element of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is an $a$th power. Implying that you can choose $y$ and $b$ any which way you want, and there will be an $x$ such that $x^a-y^b=1$.

Comment: @Piquito: are you serious? Try actually reading my comment:  when $a$ and $b$ are fixed there are solutions for large enough $p$. If you allow $a$ and $b$ to vary as well the question is totally trivial.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen.- Not your cases but I have seen already the problem is easier than I have thought. Thanks you.

Comment: @Furlo Roth.- Yes, I believe I am serious but not infallible. Mainly in reading ironic English. Regards.